# Is there an option to create different user groups by default?

Tags: login, register

I have created some prestashop sites and there is the option by default to create different user groups

example:

guest login (when visitors like to buy without registering)
customer login (when the want to create an account)
dealer login (for b2b clients)

the last group can also be assigned to pay by invoice

Is this also possible in Magento CE or would i need an extension for that?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Magento.SE, carlo!

This is totally possible in Magento.

### 1. Create new Customer groups

Log into the admin and go to `Customers > Customer Groups`. Click on "Add New Customer Group":

[image]

Enter the name and select "save":

[image]

### 2. Assign Customer Groups to specific Websites

If you want a particular customer group to be associated with a particular web store in Magento you can assign it at `System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Create New Account Options`

[image]

Now when a new customer registers with any particular store view they'll automatically be assigned to the correct group.

Comment: thanks for this answer... it will be just one store view... the wholesaler/reseller has to send an inquiry and once approved we want to create an account for them (so for wholesaler there is no auto registration)

when they log in with their assigned details, will they see different prices and different payment options?

I'm new to magento so i appologize if i ask something stupid ;-)